# how to open an ion-menu inside an ion-chip?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing my first App and I'm having a hard time opening an ion-menu inside an ion-chip. I don't know if I'm programming correctly or if it's a bug but I can't get it to open a menu.

```
<ion-chip color="dark" class="username" (click)="this.openFirst()">
      <ion-avatar>
        <img [src]="this.picture" />
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-label>{{this.userDisplayName}}</ion-label>
      <ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main" (click)="this.openFirst()">
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar color="primary">
            <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Menu Item</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-menu>
    </ion-chip>

and ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';

    constructor(private menu: MenuController) { }

  openFirst() {
    this.menu.enable(true, 'first');
    this.menu.open('first');
  }
```

Comment: Why are you opening the Whole menu inside ion chip???

Comment: i was thinking outside the box and i made this mistake but i thought a bit and then i managed to fix it

Answer (score 0):

answer:
there is no way to put ion-menu inside the ion-chip. should be placed in "main", in my case it's the wrapper. example:

```
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="wrapper">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-button (click)="this.toggleFirst()">
          <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      

      <ion-title>Configurações</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="calendar" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Alterar Data Nascimento</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="globe" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Alterar Idioma</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="lock-closed" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Alterar Senha</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button (click)="this.openTutorial()">
        <ion-icon name="tv-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Tutorial</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="tv-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Contato</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="tv-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Sobre</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="tv-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Notificações</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="tv-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Posição Nacimento</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item button>
        <ion-icon name="log-out" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Logout</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-content id="wrapper">
  <div class="center-sea">
    <img class="sea" src="/assets/images/sea/sea-new.png" />
  </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).